# How to parse variables in querystring using Express?

Tags: javascript, express, query-string, request-object

I have a request being sent to the server:

```
"/stuff?a=a&b=b&c=c"
```

Using express, how do I get these values?

I have tried the following...

```
app.get( "/stuff?:a&:b&:c", function( req, res ){});
```

...however it does not seem to recognize the route.

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: I have not tried this, but you should try /stuff?a=:a&b=:b&c=:c

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use a query string inside a route.

In Express logic you need create a route for "/stuff". The query string will be available in `req.query`.

Comment: To add to this, Express explicitly states "Query strings are not considered when performing these matches" - http://expressjs.com/api.html

Answer (score 32):

You can declare your route directly with `/stuff`, then query parameters are accessible through `req.query`, which is a JSON object.
Here's your example:

```
app.get("/stuff", function(req, res) {
    var a = req.query.a;
    ...
});
```

In your case, `req.query` is equal to:

```
{ a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c' }
```

In Express' documentation (either 4.x and 3.x) you can find additional examples:
[Express - req.query](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query).

Comment: for long time , and i find you  thank