# How can I use "?param=X" in a route in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my nodejs and "express" application I have this:

```
app.get("/:page?", function (req, res) {
  var pg = req.params.page;
```

which corresponds to `localhost:123` or `localhost:123/3`.

However, I want to be able to get the current page the same way by `req.params.page`, **but** the url should be `localhost:123` or `localhost:123/?page=X`.

How?

Comment: You want to make the query string part of the routing; is that right? I'm pretty sure you can't do that, but it's an good question. This might be your closest duplicate: [Pre-routing with querystrings with Express in Node JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909465/pre-routing-with-querystrings-with-express-in-node-js)

Comment: Possibly a closer duplicate: [How to parse variables in querystring using Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669669/how-to-parse-variables-in-querystring-using-express) ("Query strings are not considered when performing these [route] matches...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion is that you do not define your endpoint with `/:variable`.  This will then match any route you create that follows that pattern.  You should instead use something like `/pages/:page` to get a specific page

Then, you should use the URL parameter functionality in Express to include a URL parameter.

Define your route like this:

```
app.get("/pages/:page", function (req, res) {
    var pg = undefined;

    if (req.query.page) {
        pg = req.query.page;
    }
}
```

You can then access the page in req.query.page if it exists and do whatever you want with that value.

So for example, you could submit a request with `localhost/pages/123?page=3`.

`req.query.page` would equal 3 and `req.params.page` would equal 123.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead define your route without the `?` and if you do a get operation, for example on `localhost:123/3?this=that` then the `req.query.this` will be populated with the value `that`