# How to use ? as separator in webservice url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

using nodejs / express, i'm trying to make a webservice using ? to separate url from parameters and then & as parameters separators.

when using this, it works

```
app.get("/tableref/:event/:queryObject", function(req, res) {})
```

or this one works also

```
app.get("/tableref:event&:queryObject", function(req, res) {})
```

but not this, I got 404 error:

```
app.get("/tableref?:event&:queryObject", function(req, res) {})
```

It seems that it is the ? that is the problem. Is there a way to authorize it? escape it?

I'd like to use express validator like  [this](https://tinaciousdesign.com/blog/express-route-param-validation-nodejs/)

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be confusing routing with standard GET parameters, which are accessed via `req.query.[PARAM_NAME]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse variables in querystring using Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669669/how-to-parse-variables-in-querystring-using-express)

Comment: I suggest you to take 5minutes to read this ; https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

Comment: it is because I want os use express-validator to validate params like this: https://tinaciousdesign.com/blog/express-route-param-validation-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

To get value from `query string` you don't need to specify those `query string parameters` in Express routes.

Your code should look like this

```
app.get("/tableref", function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.query)
});
```

when you enter the URL `localhost/tableref?hello&world` you will get the response `{"hello": "", "world": ""}`

and if you want to pass data to `query string` variables, you can also enter the URL `localhost/tableref?hello=world&foo=bar` and you will get the response `{"hello": "world", "foo": "bar"}`

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I still have the 404 error with the \ to escape

Comment: @dtdino sorry for the previous code. It was my fault. Now my code is updated and I'm sure it solves your problem and works for you. Please test it again and tell me if it works now.

Comment: Yep, it works and it is what I had before I wanted to change for implementing express-validator like this https://tinaciousdesign.com/blog/express-route-param-validation-nodejs/ . So it is not really what I want.